# How to convert MutableList<Int> to IntArray in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

I want to convert MutableList to IntArray. I am using toTypedArray() to convert but its resulting in Exception:

```
Line 15: Char 23: error: type inference failed. Expected type mismatch: inferred type is Array&lt;Int&gt; but IntArray was expected
        return result.toTypedArray()
                  ^
```

Below is full code :

```
fun intersection(nums1: IntArray, nums2: IntArray): IntArray {
            val set: MutableSet<Int> = mutableSetOf()
            val result: MutableList<Int> = mutableListOf()

            for(num in nums1) set.add(num)

            for(num in nums2) {
                if(set.contains(num)) {
                    result.add(num)
                    set.remove(num)
                }
            }

            return result.toTypedArray()
        }
```

Comment: Can't you just `return result.toIntArray()`?

Comment: This already exists as [`intersect`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/intersect.html), `(nums1 intersect nums2).toIntArray()`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have an extension function `toIntArray()`

Example:

```
mutableListOf<Int>(1, 3, 4).toIntArray()
```

Or in case of `mutableSetOf`:

```
mutableSetOf<Int>(1 ,3 ,4).toIntArray()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
.toTypedArray() for Array<Int>
.toIntArray() for IntArray
```